# UIStackView, dynamically new element should always be added to the top of the list

Tags: swift, xcode, uistackview

I have one element in UIStackView. Then, I add the elements dynamically as follows.

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
```

However, they always add these elements to the end of the stackview. How can I make the new addition always add to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(view, at: 0)
```

which inserts to view at the start.